# AsyncTask - slow download

Tags: android, android-asynctask, download

I am using AsyncTask to download ~50 MB files from internet. Sometimes, when I download this file, progress bar gain is very slow (even when I am on Wi-Fi). And after minute, phone shows me, download complete, but the file itself has only ~100kB, no more. But when I restart device, and try to download file, download is executed briefly and quick. Has anyone faced same problem? Do I need to erase same download memory before downloading new file? I am downloading file to Environment.externalStoryDirectory().

Thx

**Calling download from activity:**

```
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ItemDetails.this);
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Downloading");
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading sth...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
            mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            DownloadMapTask downloadFile = new DownloadMapTask(ItemDetails.this);
            downloadFile.execute(web_location_url);
            mProgressDialog.show();
```

**Download Async Task (two methods):**

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    int count;

    PATH=maps_loc+"/Android/data/test/maps/";

    try {
        URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
        HttpURLConnection connection2 = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection2.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection2.setDoOutput(true);
        connection2.connect();
        int lenghtOfFile = connection2.getContentLength();

        File apkdir = new File(PATH);
        apkdir.mkdirs();

        File newInstall = new File(PATH, name+".tmp");

        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(newInstall);

        byte data[] = new byte[1024];

        long total = 0;

        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1 && running==true) {
            total += count;
            publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / lenghtOfFile));
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;

}

public void onProgressUpdate(Integer... args) {

    ItemDetails.mProgressDialog.setProgress(args[0]);

}
```

Comment: can you please show us some code...?

Comment: You might also examine your logs. It may be gc or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some servers will close the connection if the client has slow speed and the download takes long time, which can be the case if your program is connected to the Internet through mobile data not Wi-Fi.

You should consider supporting **download resume** in your program to not start from scratch every time.

I do not think there is sort of *download memory* that you need to clear. I have an app that can easily downloads over 50MB with no problems.

Also, you might consider obtaining a `lock` for both Wi-Fi and processor to keep your program running until the download finishes.

**Edit**

In your code, try to print the value `lenghtOfFile` after the line `int lenghtOfFile = connection2.getContentLength();` to make sure that it is the same as the actual file size you are downloading.

Below is alternative example code which supports `resume` that I am using in my projects. (it is just to illustrate the idea, you will need to modify the code to your needs)

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(new URI(fileURL)));
HttpResponse response;
InputStream is = null;
FileOutputStream fos = null;
try {

    boolean continueDownloading = false;
    String tmpFileName = fileName + "_tmp";
    outputFile = new File(downloadFolder, tmpFileName);
    if (outputFile.exists()) {
            localFileLength = outputFile.length();
            if (localFileLength > 0) {
                    continueDownloading = true;
            } 

            if (continueDownloading) {
                    request.addHeader("Range", "bytes=" + localFileLength + "-");
            }

            response = httpClient.execute(request);

            long remoteFileLength = 0;
            Header contentLengthHeader = response.getFirstHeader("Content-Length");
            if (contentLengthHeader != null) {
                    remoteFileLength = Integer.parseInt(contentLengthHeader.getValue());
            }

            long downloaded = 0;

            if (continueDownloading) {
                    downloaded = localFileLength;
            }

            long fullFileLength = downloaded + remoteFileLength;

            fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile, true);

            is = response.getEntity().getContent();


            byte[] buffer = new byte[DOWNLOAD_BUFFER_SIZE];
            int len = 0;
            while ((len = is.read(buffer)) != -1 && isDownloading) {
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
                    downloaded += len;                                      
            }

            fos.flush();

            boolean success = downloaded == fullFileLength;
            if (success) {
                    outputFile.renameTo(new File(downloadFolder, fileName));
            }

    } catch (Throwable ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();               
    } finally {
       // clean up resources
    }
```

Comment: I haven't mentioned it, I have this problem, while on Wi-Fi, which works normally, by the way

Comment: So make sure that you have appropriate `lock` to keep your program active during the download

Answer (score 0):

Try using downloadManager instead of downloading manually , there are many advantages to using it.

Here is an example for it : [DownloadManager Example](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/download-manager-in-android-programming/)

and take a look at the documentations : [DownloadManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html)

Comment: My app have to staz backwards compatible with Android 2.1+, so I can|t use download manager :(

Comment: you can use it for 2.3+ devices. and improve your manual download implementation for 2.2 and 2.1